# What's the best way for displaying a three-level category tree?

Tags: categories, channel-entries

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:
A three-level 'category' tree, with at the end channel_entries.
So users can browse between categories & access the entries related to that category.

- Category A

  - Category A.1

    - Entries
  - Category A.2

    - Entries
- Category B

  - Category B.1

    - Category B.1.1

      - Entries
    - Category B.1.2

      - Entries
- Category C

I'm already using the **Child Categories**-plugin,
but it seems like you can't access categories in such 'depth':

> Hi,
>   This add-on supports only 2 levels of categories, i.e. you can display parents and children,
>   but not grandchildren.

I also tried a combination between the native category tag & child categories,
but no success so far...

Or am I better off by writing a custom query?

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried GWCode Categories? I always use this add-on for category stuff, it's great. If this works out for you, I made an official answer since this is more or less a question/suggestion. http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with [gwcode-categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories): **it allows you to target categories by depth**.

F.ex:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="example" depth="3"}
    {cat_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

You can find more info in the [docs](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/examples/example3).

Anyway, your code should be something along these lines:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="example"}
    {cat_name}
    {if depth == 3}
        <ul>
            {exp:channel:entries channel="example" category="{cat_id}"}
                <li>
                    {title}
                </li>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        </ul>
    {/if}
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="example"}
```

Comment: But remember that the depth-attribute in gwcode-categories always addresses an ABSOLUTE depth, i.e. depth 1 is always root-level.